# Docker ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

Tags: python, docker, scipy, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm exploring Python through building its Docker image. I want to use the `scipy` library but I'm not able to import it for some reason. Here are the imports for my `__init.py__` file:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp
from flask import Flask, g
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
numpy==1.19.0
scipy==0.15.1
Flask==0.12.2
markdown==2.6.11
flask-restful==0.3.6
```

And finally my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
        calculator:
                build: .
                volumes:
                        - .:/usr/src/app
                ports:
                        - 5000:80
```

Now when I do a `docker-compose up` this is the error:

```
calculator  | Traceback (most recent call last):
calculator  |   File "./run.py", line 1, in <module>
calculator  |     from probability_calculator import app
calculator  |   File "/usr/src/app/probability_calculator/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
calculator  |     import scipy.stats as sp
calculator  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

I've had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732303/docker-unable-to-install-numpy-scipy-or-gensim) but adding those lines to the `Dockerfile` still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Dan apologies, have just added that file.

Comment: What are the logs saying when this line runs `RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`? Seems like scipy isn't getting installed but numpy is, the logs should indicate this

Comment: btw that is a very old version of scipy, maybe use a newer one?

Comment: thanks @Dan that's actually worked after I upgraded it to 1.4.1, that'll teach me to straight copy and paste too often...

Comment: I will bet you that you could diagnose this from the logs of that pip install line. I would be that numpy 1.19 has a minimum requirement on scipy above 0.15 and that pip would have logged that it wasn't going to install scipy or that something went wrong at the point.

Answer (score 0):

Answer- `requirements.txt` had an old version of `scipy` so it wasn't working, I bumped it up to 1.4.1 and it seems to work now.